# Array data pointing to another position in another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

In my C project i ask the user to prompt some information.

For example:

`"What lines are white ?"`

The user prompt the number of the line who is white:

`3 4 6` line etc.

I know that every line has a unique position in a `4x4` matrix.

For example:
- line 3: `matrix[3][2]`,
- line 2: `matrix[3][3]` etc..

When the user says a line my program must "color" the right cell in the matrix writing X in the cell.

I don't know how to map a certain position in the matrix for a certain "number of a line". I want to make a type of dictionary,for example 3: `&matrix[2][2]`.

How to do this? I don't want to specify line by line the position for example:

`int line3 = &matrix[2][2]` and so on...

I want to use an array if it's possibile..I hope I was clear..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try something so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this option:
we define for the matrix a vector of pointers.
for example a 4x4 matrix:

```
int matrix[4][4];
int *mapVector[4*4];
```

for mapping any line in the vector we do

```
mapVector[i] = &matric[x][y];
```

if we want to set the value of line 3 for example we only write:

```
*mapVector[3] = X;
```

and the position in the matrix will be automatically updated.

Comment: Yes this si the solution i want use but there si a way to declare the vector for all the cells without specify positions? For example instead of use vector[3]=.. Vector[4]= etc.. Can i declare it like a normal vector? Vector[16]={cell1pointer,cell2 etc... ?

Comment: if you want to map line number to a specific position in the matrix, you must set for every line the position where it is situated in the matrix. otherwise I don't see any reason for mapping. if you are using a trivial mapping for example: line[0] in matrix[0][0] .... in this situation you don't need to set every line separately, you can write int \*mapVector = (int\*)matirx; and for setting values write only \*mapVector[0] = ...

Comment: I see but i must set every value of the vector separately not together in one declaration

Comment: i hope this could be helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a structure, like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int lineNumber;
    int isWhite;
} line;

line matrix[4][4];
```

Comment: I already tried this approach,but i need to separate the matrix from the lines.. i explain better,my real project is to make a program for the karnaugh map,so each cell of the matrix in this case 4x4 correspond to a combination of variables in the boolean function. For example 0000 is the cell [0][0] and so on. My answer is in C there are no other methods to to this except by using a struct?